# Euler Criterion Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be a prime number. Prove that
$$\frac{(np)!}{n!p^n}≡ (−1)^n$$ (mod p)

I've recently learnt about Wilson's theorem, Eulers Criterion and computing the Legendre Symbol, and I'm unsure how to going about tackling this problem.

Comment: Hint: try induction.

Comment: so assume true for n=k and prove its true for n=k+1?

Comment: Yes, this is how induction works. You also need to check $n=1$ (or $n=0$ if you are also considering this case)

Comment: This is straightforward from Wilson's...

Answer (score 0):

For

$$n=1\implies\frac{(np)!}{n!p^n}=\frac{p!}{1\cdot p}=(p-1)!=-1\pmod p=(-1)^1\pmod p$$

Assume until $\;n-1\;$ and now prove for $\;n\;$ :

$$\frac{(np)!}{n!p^n}=\frac{((n-1)p)!}{(n-1)!p^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{(np-p+1)(np-p+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot np}{np}\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=$$

$$=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot\overbrace{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot(np-1)}^{\text{complete set of representatives modulo}\;p}\pmod p=(-1)^n\pmod p $$